# Disable/alter behavior of "swipe from left" on iPad with master/detail configuration

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have a master/detail split view configuration in my iPad application. If I swipe from the left (or really, just swipe *to the right* in the detail view, regardless of whether I start at the left edge of the screen or not) it slides open the master view.

The issue here is that my detail view is an `MKMapView`, so if I put my finger on the map and move my finger to the right (to pan left) the master view opens! I have to *start* dragging my finger in some other direction, and *then* go right, to properly pan.

Can this behavior be altered either:

1. So it is disabled completely (only allowing opening the master view from the back button)
2. So it only affects swipes in the detail view that are *not* over the map
3. So it only triggers if the swipe starts from the edge of the screen

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes,** you can disable that behavior. Set the [`presentsWithGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISplitViewController/presentsWithGesture) property of the split view controller to `NO` to disable the swiping gesture.

Comment: Perfect - I don't know how I missed that. I'll accept when SO lets me in a few minutes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what the IsGestureEnabled setting is for on the MasterDetailPage?