# How to disable swipe back gesture with master-detail view in ios 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I'm trying to disable the swipe back gesture, so that swiping back in my detail view will not open the master view.

I'm aware that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209468/how-to-disable-back-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-on-ios-7) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187031/disable-alter-behavior-of-swipe-from-left-on-ipad-with-master-detail-configura) exist, but I have tried all the solutions suggested and none of them have worked for me. It may be because I am on iOS 11.

To demonstrate the issue, I've created a new master-detail project in Xcode and only added the solutions which I saw in the linked questions, which is adding this:

```
self.splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = NO;
```

To the `viewDidLoad` of the MasterViewController and adding this

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

To the DetailViewController

MasterViewController

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *objects;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
    self.splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = NO;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController.isCollapsed;
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    if (!self.objects) {
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}


#pragma mark - Segues

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        [controller setDetailItem:object];
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    }
}


#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.objects.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}


@end
```

DetailViewController

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)configureView {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
}


#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(NSDate *)newDetailItem {
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}


@end
```

AppDelegate

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
    splitViewController.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


#pragma mark - Split view

- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    if ([secondaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && [[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]] && ([(DetailViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] detailItem] == nil)) {
        // Return YES to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

How do I disable the swipe back feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add this to my DetailViewController

```
id savedGestureRecognizerDelegate1;
id savedGestureRecognizerDelegate2;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        savedGestureRecognizerDelegate1 = self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        savedGestureRecognizerDelegate2 = self.navigationController.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate;
        self.navigationController.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = savedGestureRecognizerDelegate1;
    }
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = savedGestureRecognizerDelegate2;
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer || gestureRecognizer == self.navigationController.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This is because there's two navigation controllers in a split view controller. The saved gesture recognizer delegate is because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27600715/5605365).

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

This line definitely worked for me. Anyway, I suggest you moving it to the viewDidLoad function so it is executed just once.

Comment: This doesn't work and there's nothing in my project that would make it unique. It's literally just the autogenerated xcode master-detail app with that one line added to the viewDidLoad function. Run in the iphone 7 emulator.

Comment: Wait, you were putting that line in the DetailViewController, right?

Comment: Is there some way I can look at the project you were building this in?

Comment: Right in the DetailViewController. Sorry, I can't share the project.

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

}

For Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

But it is not recommended.
Find [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209468/how-to-disable-back-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-on-ios-7)